# Does the bonus die for Captain of the Guard's Battle Steed ability have to be assigned a target color before the roll?

Tags: defenders-of-the-realm

One of the new heroes in Expansion #1 is Captain of the Guard, and he gets a bonus die when initiating attack in a new location. Does this extra die have to be assigned to a color of minion on that location?

For instance, I move to a location with 1 red and 1 blue minion, I can roll 1 red and 1 blue die, plus 1 bonus (assume I choose a green die for my bonus). If this is my roll: Red 3; Blue 2; Green 5.  Can I use the green die to eliminate the blue minion? Can I  choose *after* the roll, or do I have to assign a color to my bonus *before* the roll?

The Elf Lord character has a similar bonus, but has to choose before the roll. The Captain of the Guard character card does not specify. We played a game last night with both of these characters, and for the Elf Lord, he chose before the roll. For the Captain, I used my bonus die as a wild card and assigned it based on the roll results. I want to know of I played correctly or not.

I am looking for official errata or clarification from the game designer. I've been told it exists, but have not found it for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a wildcard -- instead, you choose which die to focus on.  If you're in an area with 2 red minions, and 1 blue minion, you can roll 3-1, or 2-2.

Link:  [Official Clarification by Richard Launius (designer.)](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/669986/two-rule-questions-new-hero-abilities)